# How to create a style for an unstyled control

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, vcl-styles

I'm currently messing arround with [Embarcadero's Bitmap Style Designer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Bitmap_Style_Designer) on Delphi 10 Seattle.
As far as I know, you can mess arround with the objects that Embarcadero gives you, but when it comes to the yet unstyled parts of the control nothing can be found.
Also, I know there are ways to create new object styles, more details in its [docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Bitmap_Style_Designer).

Just so you can know what I'm talking about:
[image: Bitmap Style Designer Sample]
Now, my question is: Is there a way to create a Style for the area circled in red?

Comment: You appear to be looking in the wrong place. What you have enclosed in red is `CategoryPanelGroup` but in your screenshot, you're looking at `CategoryButtons`.

Comment: Also, I would recommend not using that particular control - I've had all sorts of issues with it not redrawing - leaving an ugly empty white space. I've abandoned this control.

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I wanted to fix this issue, that's how I've learned about the bitmap designer.
Also, `CategoryPanelGroup` is not related with `CategoryButtons`, I've already tried that out.
I can change that area's color, but it leaves the ugly empty white space as you've mentioned.

Comment: Ahh, it seems you're right, there's another control for that. This control (both actually) are very under-developed, and modifying the style won't make it any better. I have this problem whether I'm using styles or not. The actual rendering inside the control itself is broken - changing the style won't have any effect.

Comment: I thought so too, but when I'm using the default style from windows, the IDE gives you this property [TCategoryButtons.Color](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.CategoryButtons.TCategoryButtons.Color) which changes that ugly empty space, but still, that only works when I'm using default windows styling. It still gives me hope you know? :D